# Fetch API: how can I access the payload of a chunked response?

Tags: javascript, http, fetch

I'm making a simple GET request using the Fetch API and the response has:

`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`

The network inspector in the Firefox dev tools shows me a chunk (a partial JSON response) in the payload, but I can't figure out how to access it in JavaScript.

Interestingly, even though the response status is 200, `response.ok` is `false`.

So how can I access the payload?

Comment: I observe the same behavior. It seems browsers don't properly implement fetch for Transfer-Encoding: chunked responses. I will try to just return the response without specifying that transfer encoding and without separating chunks, just sending data slowly over the tcp socket...

Comment: hmm, I got it working by using CORS properly, i.e. removing `mode: 'no-cors',`

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the fetch response's [body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/body) field, which is a stream like object with support for streaming reads. As long as you're reading data you've received, you should be OK to process it in a streaming manner.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader) is an example of using the `Reader` associated with the body stream to read chunks.

Comment: unfortunately, `response.body` is `undefined`, which was the surprise that sent me here. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Does that change when you receive the whole response?